# Discordpy, Show a description depening on what lang/role has the user in slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to try to make that depending on the lang that the user has on discord, or, if he has X or Y role show a specific description of a command, in order to make it to has 2 languages, Spanish/English.

Looking something like this:

[image]
[image]

How can this be done in python with this the library [discord-py-slash-command](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/)?

Here is some code to edit it if needed:

```
#COMANDO status
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='Status', description='Nasgar Status')
async def status(self,ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id == cmd_channel:
        server = JavaServer.lookup(ip_nasgar)
        status = server.status()
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title=f'Server Status',
            url="",
            description=f'**IP** ➤ {ip_nasgar}\n\n**Players** ➤ {status.players.online}',
            color=embed_color
            )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=img_thumbnail)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Has discord.py added Slash commands yet? Or are you using another package to add them? I know that localization of slash commands is possible in Disnake (a discord.py fork) https://docs.disnake.dev/en/latest/ext/commands/slash_commands.html#localizations

Comment: @Nik They haven't adeed it yet, and i'm using as i said in the question `discord-py-slash-command `

Comment: Sorry I missed that info. In the documentation it looks like the Application command class has the properties `name_localizations` and `description_localizations` https://interactionspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.command.html

Comment: @Nik and how would this be done? I didn’t understand it very well